# Powershell to add text to homepage of SP2013 sites

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

I'm in desperate need of your help on creating a powershell script to add text to a SP2013 sites that we're migrating content from. I'd essentially like to add a banner that says 'site is now locked and no longer in use' to site homepages.

I found this article but it's dated as it uses snappin which I understand is no longer supported and superseded by PnP. Any help on how to convert this to a PnP or other supported powershell?

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/add-content-editor-web-part-on-the-sharepoint-2013-sites-using-powershell

I will be getting site URls from a csv list which I can script but it's cadding text content webpage on homepages if what I can't seem to do?

Comment: Is there anything you have written so far to solve your issue?

Comment: Is there a programmatic way in SP 2013 to add this content flag before migration? That could spare you a ton of headache.